# How to bind to user control's parent window IsActive property

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, user-controls, window

I had my WPF control set so that it had only the following code:

```
  InitializeComponent();
  DataContext = model;
```

However, I now run into a problem where I do not want certain actions to occur while the window is not active, so I created an IsActive flag on my ViewModel, but as my code is coming from a user control, and not a window, I cannot do this without code behind in my user control. Is this the best I can do, or is there a true MVVM approach to this

Tried this, but ran into a runtime error saying that the `IsActiveProperty` cannot be data bound.

```
 Loaded += (sender, args) =>
              {
                var parentWindow = Window.GetWindow(this);
                if (parentWindow == null)
                  return;
                var isActiveWindowBinding = new Binding {Source = model.IsActive};
                parentWindow.SetBinding(Window.IsActiveProperty, isActiveWindowBinding);
              };
```

So, I am not doing this:

```
 Loaded += (sender, args) =>
              {
                var parentWindow = Window.GetWindow(this);
                if (parentWindow == null)
                  return;
                parentWindow.Activated += (o, eventArgs) => model.IsActive = true;
                parentWindow.Deactivated += (o, eventArgs) => model.IsActive = false;
              };
```

The biggest problem is that I cannot get the parent window until the control loads and databinding has already been completed? Would I have to create an attached behavior, which is quite a lot of pain for a simple binding.

Comment: Have you tried changing the binding to 'var isActiveWindowBinding = new Binding("IsActive") {Source = model.IsActive, UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged};' where your IsActive **property** implements a PropertyChanged method

Comment: @Bob I will try that, but it still pollutes what could be such a clean code-behind, which is the main part of my question

Answer (score 0):

Does not binding work?

```
<Window IsActive="{Binding Path=IsActive, Mode=OneWayToSource}"/>
```

Here is meant that DataContext of the window is set.

Or if you want to use window's state in user control markup, try this binding:

```
PropValue="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window}, Path=IsActive}"
```

Comment: This is a user control, not a window.

Comment: I thought of that already, but what is PropValue? That would need to be the IsActive, which is only on the Window, not the UserControl

Comment: Now I do not understand what you want. Window has its IsActive property. Depending on its value you want to enable or disable actions in you ViewModel/UserControl?

Comment: I have a user control that I would like to bind it's parent windows property to the user control's model. I do not know the Window until runtime, though.

Comment: This can be a kind of solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7538314/how-to-use-binding-like-proxy

Comment: Yah, that is (as far I understand them) an attached behavior. Quite a bit of work for a couple of lines of code to be removed from your backend...if that is my only solution, then I may just deal with it...

Comment: By the way, bidnig with relativesource does not work for UserControl.
The error is returned:
System.Windows.Data Warning: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with reference 'RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType='System.Windows.Window', AncestorLevel='1''

Comment: `<Window IsActive="{Binding Path=IsActive, Mode=OneWayToSource}"/>` doesn't work for me - I get an error saying 'The property "IsActive" does not have an accessible setter.'

Comment: @komodosp, true. My fault. Well, as a workaround, you can introduce attached property which will call window's 'Activate()` method.