# WPF how to access other variable from same viewmodel?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, telerik, relativesource

To display items on `Telerik:RadGridView` usually I use `DataContext="{Binding [someViewModel]}"` and `ItemSource="{Binding objectList, Mode=TwoWay}"`.

and for my column I'll access the `objectfield`. The overall picture will be something like below:

```
<telerik:RadGridView DataContext="{Binding [someViewModel]}" 
     ItemSource="{Binding objectList, Mode=TwoWay}">

    <telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
            <telerik:GridViewDataColumn>
                <telerik:GridViewDataColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <CheckBox IsEnabled="{Binding enabledVar}" 
                            IsChecked="{Binding isChecked, Mode=Twoway}"
                    </DataTemplate>
                </telerik:GridViewDataColumn.CellTemplate>

            </telerik:GridViewDataColumn>  
    </telerik:RadGridView.Columns>

</telerik:RadGridView>
```

Imagine there will be 10 items in `objectList`. Each of the item in `objectList` will have a variable `isChecked` which to manipulate the checkbox `IsChecked` property.

I have another variable in the same viewmodel named `enabledVar` which to control the ten checkbox `IsEnabled` property. `enabledVar` is not part of the `objectList` but I couldn't get the value. May I know how to handle such case?

**Updates:**

I've found some new direction but not sure if it helps.

```
<CheckBox IsEnabled="{Binding enabledVar,
     RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, 
     AncestorType=telerik:RadGridView}}"
```

but then of course, still failed.

Any helps would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if using Ancestor you have to bind to DataContext

```
<CheckBox IsEnabled="{Binding Path=DataContext.enabledVar,
     RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, 
     AncestorType=telerik:RadGridView}}"
```

Another aproach could be to use element binding set name

```
<telerik:RadGridView x:Name="myGrid" ...
```

And then in the celltemplate bind to it

```
<CheckBox IsEnabled="{Binding Path=DataContext.enabledVar, ElementName=myGrid}"
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The code suggested in Update will not work because GridViewDataColumn is not part of the Visual tree, and hence can not access DataContext.

You will have to make use of proxy data binding, like suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7538314/how-to-use-binding-like-proxy). You can get more examples by searching "wpf proxy databinding".